# using .NET MF for implementing digital reflectance sensor?

Tags: c#, sensors, .net-micro-framework

I'm using .NET MF with a microcontroller and a digital reflectance sensor. I need to implement the following pseudocode in C# to read from the sensor. I am using GHIElectronics.NETMF.FEZ for input/output ports. This is the product I'm using http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9454

```
int QRE1113_Pin = 2; //connected to digital 2

void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

int QRE_Value = readQD();
Serial.println(QRE_Value); 

}

int readQD(){
//Returns value from the QRE1113 
//Lower numbers mean more refleacive
//More than 3000 means nothing was reflected.
pinMode( QRE1113_Pin, OUTPUT );
digitalWrite( QRE1113_Pin, HIGH );
delayMicroseconds(10);
pinMode( QRE1113_Pin, INPUT );

long time = micros();

//time how long the input is HIGH, but quit after 3ms as nothing happens after that
while (digitalRead(QRE1113_Pin) == HIGH && micros() - time < 3000);
int diff = micros() - time;

return diff;
```

EDIT: I'm using

```
new InputPort((Cpu.Pin)FEZ_Pin.Digital.IO44, false, Port.ResistorMode.Disabled)
```

to create inputports and

```
new OutputPort((Cpu.Pin)FEZ_Pin.Digital.IO44, false)
```

to create outputports, but I don't know how to change pin mode from Out to In or set a pin as HIGH

Comment: Except for a missing last curly brace `}` it looks like perfectly valid c# code already. What part is "pseudo"?